# jquery - make toggle switch appear above body when body is dimmed

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

I'm using this script https://github.com/andywer/jquery-dim-background to dim my page on a toggle switch. However, when the page has been dimmed I lose the ability to toggle the switch. My code is below. You can also view it in action here http://www.fospower.com/test

Any help is well appreciated.

```
$(function() {
    $('input#lightswitch').iToggle({
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        onClickOn:function() {
            //$('input:checkbox').addClass('iT_checkbox_on');
            $('input:radio').addClass('iT_checkbox_on');
            $(this).dimBackground({
                darkness:0.8
            }, function() {

            });
        },
        onClickOff:function() {
            //$('input:checkbox').removeClass('iT_checkbox_on');
            $('input:radio').removeClass('iT_checkbox_on');
            $(this).undim();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply add `pointer-events:none;` to the inline css of `.dimbackground-curtain` you will be able to click on the switch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the z-index of the curtain layer being generated by the jquery script is placing it above your other elements like the toggle switch. Try adjusting the z-index of your toggle switch in your functions so the switch is moved to the top when the "curtain" is applied, and reversed when the "curtain" is removed.

Comment: I've actually tried that DaCronDon214. I've given the overlay a z-index of 1 and the lightswitch a higher z-index but no avail.